# How can I filter the auto populate when editing a form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, when you go to the edit action, it automatically pulls the information from the models and populates the form. If I had a CRUD that saves sensitive information, for example password or ssn, how can I filter the values so that it doesn't just show it in plaintext when editing the form?

I was going to change the value in the controller by setting it to `****`, but the potential risk there is people may submit the form and it will update the SSN to `****`.

I'm not referring to filtering the params so it doesn't show up in console (config.filter_parameters).

Comment: you can manually set value in fields to nil, so your info won't be shown, or in variable that on your edit action you can set unsafe values to nil, so they wont be shown on form as well

Answer (score 0):

Changing the input field to type="password" should resolve your problem. Just don't set the fields in the controller if they are blank.

If you are using a form builder, change text_field to password_field.

Comment: I tried that, but the value in the HTML still shows it in plain sight. I am using `form_for`, fyi.

Comment: Can you post your code for the input fields because passwords should definitely not be visible.